# Does MySQL always run foreign key constraint checks when a row is updated? Or only when a relevant column is changed?

Tags: mysql, update, foreign-key, constraint

I have this question and I haven't found specific documentation to confirm the behavior and am unaware of how to manually check this myself.

Consider I have table A with b_id foreign key to table B. If I run an update on a row in table A, does mysql always run the foreign key constraint check on table B even if A's b_id goes unchanged or isn't passed in the update statement? such as `(select 1 from B where id = ?)`

Example:

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x", A.b_id = 1 where A.id = 1` I know this runs the foreign key check on B

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x" where A.id = 1` But does this also run the foreign key check even though b_id goes unchanged since it was not passed?

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x" A.b_id = A.b_id where A.id = 1` And what about this? b_id gets passed in with same existing value. Does the fk check run?

Any supporting documentation or help would be appreciated, as well as tips on how I can test this sort of behavior myself since using `EXPLAIN` doesn't help.

Comment: Write a test case and let us know what you get.